# Publishing app with Eclipse and IBM BlueMix Tools never completes

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

When pushing my WAR to a Liberty server in Bluemix using the IBM Bluemix tool (v1.0.3) it gets to 80% and never completes.

The logs look like it finished, but Eclipse doesn't acknowledge. I can push from the cf command line just fine.

[image: Eclipse Progress not complete]

[image: Version of Bluemix Tools]

Comment: In Bluemix 1.0.3, the issue with the loggregator has been fixed. The message.log file (which is the Liberty logs) on Bluemix will now be read to determine if the application has started. I have 3 questions:
1. Can you describe your scenario in detail? I have been unable to reproduce the problem you've described.
2. Based on the progress, it looks like you do a "Push" when your application has been published. Do you see the same problem if you select the Bluemix server in the Servers View > right click on the server > Publish
3. Does the hang from calling "Push" happen 100% of the time? (i.e. i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I meet this issue from time to time too and yes it's usually due to the loggregator related issue. You can cancel the progress and the app status will usually get reflected correctly in the Eclipse server view.

Comment: Yes I can cancel it, but it sticks around.  Just annoying :)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this behavior sometimes too. I usually cancel the process and it does not hurt anything. I will take this feedback to our dev team.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this may be happening because of issues connecting to the loggregator process. If you have CF CLI installed, can you successfully do `cf logs <app name>` or `cf logs <app name> --recent` ?

Comment: Good question, but yes. I do have the CF CLI installed and the logs do work.  I routinely review the logs and deploy via the command-line.